# How can I get this anime.js to work in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gatsby, anime.js

How can I get this code to work in React/Gatsby. When I go to build it fails

window.addEventListener("mousemove", move);

window.onload = () => animejs({
targets: ".cursor",
opacity: 1
});

Comment: In what way does it fail? Are there errors? And have you checked out the anime.js wrappers for React mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951482/how-to-use-animejs-inside-react/61962093)?

Comment: Please may you provide a runnable [mcve]? Otherwise we're kinda left guessing

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it inside this condition:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
   window.addEventListener("mousemove", move);

   window.onload = () => animejs({ targets: ".cursor", opacity: 1 });

 }
```

You need to understand Gatsby to know what's going on. As a summary, `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser-side, where there's a [`window` (or other global objects like `document`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) so your code won't break. `gatsby build` occurs in the server where obviously there's no `window` (because it's not even defined yet), so every portion of code that uses `window` without validation, will break.

Wrapping the code inside the previous condition will make your code work.